# Trying to use join() on what I think is an array is throwing an no method error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of labels.  I want to get the text in each of those labels and join the text together into a comma-separated string.  Here is what I have:

```
var listArray = $("#filter_tag_list lable").map(function(){return $(this).text()})
var listString = listArray.join();
```

In the console I can see that listArray consists of the correct-looking array: `["test input 1", "test input 2"]`.  But I'm getting a `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'join'`.  Note, if I manually create an array `a = ["test input 1", "test input 2"]`, then `a.join()` works just fine.

What am I not getting about the typing of listArray???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `map` does not return an array, it returns a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery). Use `.get()` at the to turn the jQuery object into a true array:

```
var listArray = $("#filter_tag_list lable").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get(); // <----

var listString = listArray.join();
```

This is outlined in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/map):

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery map returns an object, so you must first convert to an array using `toArray`:

```
var listArray = $("#filter_tag_list lable").map(function(){return $(this).text()}).toArray();
```